# Sci fi short story about humans diverging genetically after contact with aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi

A while ago (about 2016) I read an illustrated pdf about human colonization of outer space. First they fought, Martians with Earthers, then they had some kind of homo novus and, afterwards, they started colonizing space and diverging. Much later, they found some aliens, who subjugated them and transformed them into near-animals, some of them with sentience, but many without. Some were mutated into giraffe-like animals, grazing, and they had sentience at first but they lost it. Others were mutated into cell-like beings that had to exchange nutrients among themselves, etc.

The pdf went on with many subspecies. I think it was self-published on the internet, not ever printed.

Comment: Could you [edit] to add how long a while ago is?

Comment: Done! The pdf I saw about 2016, I think it was about that time when it was spread on the internet. I'm not even sure it had an author name, maybe it was just an anonymous.

Comment: Since the question has an accepted answer I won’t post a new one, but the theme is similar to the classic _Last and First Men_ by Olaf Stapledon, which follows the evolution of the human race and its successors for billions of years into the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds kind of like All Tomorrows:

http://www.sivatherium.narod.ru/library/Ramjet/01_en.htm

There's a pdf version of it online. The story starts with Mars being colonized by modified humans, then going to war with Earth. Then aliens attack, mutate people into several different animal like forms, and leave. The story then continues for a billion years, describing all the weird forms that the mutated humans evolve into.

Comment: In what way? Can you please elaborate on how this matches the OP's requirements?

Comment: Yes! It was exactly that.